# Aquire disassembly of shader code

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is there a way to get the disassembly that your driver generates when compiling a shader? I noticed that you can get an accidental disassembly dump if you go over the maximum thread group size supported by the hardware in compute shaders, so naturally I figured there must be some way to do this for all shader types. Is there a reliable way to get the disassembly (perhaps specific to NVIDIA/AMD/Intel hardware), using tools or even just "hacks" like causing errors during compilation / linking?

Comment: are you using Nvidia or AMD ?

Comment: if you are using AMD check this http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-shaderanalyzer/

Comment: @concept3d nvidia

Comment: I am sure you can using this tool https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-videos but unfortunately I am a hobbyist and don't have developer pass to use them :)

Comment: according to this question he is using AMD shader analyzer to convert glsl to IL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299506/glsl-branching-behaviour

Comment: @concept3d I have Nsight installed, and (at least from what I can see) it doesn't provide any options to show disassembly for GLSL code. I can't used AMD shader analyzer because I'm using an NVIDIA GPU (gtx 770).

Comment: @TravisG Checkout [Renderdoc](https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least on NVIDIA hardware, the shader assembly representation can be queried using the glGetProgramBinary() OpenGL function (initially part of the gl_arb_get_program_binary extension), which requires OpenGL 3.0 and upwards.

```
const size_t MAX_SIZE = 1<<24;
char binary[MAX_SIZE];
GLenum format;
GLint length;
glGetProgramBinary(shaderProgramObject,MAX_SIZE,&length,&format,&binary[0]);
```

You can then dump it however you want, for example (for easy copy and paste purposes of this answer) in C++:

```
std::ofstream binaryfile("bin.txt");
binaryfile.write(binary,length);
```

If you open the file with a text editor, it will contain some garbage (presumably the actual compiled binary representation of the assembly code), but at least on the three different sets of hardware and two different sets on driver versions I could test, it will also contain the assembly output of the program. Technically, the output of glGetProgramBinary is implementation (of your driver) dependent, so in the future or in older driver versions it might not contain any assembly, but it seems to work out so far.

I can't test whether AMD hardware drivers output the assembly as well, but it would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

For AMD GPUs, check out [Radeon GPU Analyzer](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/RGA/releases) -

Using this you can generate ISA disassembly and performance statistics for DX11, OpenGL and Vulkan shaders, and for OpenCL kernels.